# Подсчет людей в помещении с помощью компьютерного зрения и камеры

Tags: java, c++, python, opencv

Пытаюсь написать программу для подсчета людей в помещении (кабинет в офисе, аудитория со студентами). Нашел несколько готовых решений, но работают они только при условии что люди относительно быстро двигаются (если говорить о видео) или если хорошо различимы черты лица и/или форма тела.

Предположим, что камера установлена сверху (как [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0o958Dgg0w)). Есть ли у кого идеи как посчитать людей, пусть даже с небольшой погрешностью, в помещении при условии что большинство из них сидят и мало двигаются. В своих попытках использую Python + OpenCV, но язык и технология реализации не имеют значения.

Comment: Задача подсчета людей в помещении стоит давно и не падает. Эта задача важна для торговли (подсчет посетителей в супермаркете), для транспорта (подсчет количества зайцев) и в других местах. В общем случае задача сейчас не решена. И, похоже, будет решена только когда появится искусственный интеллект. :-) Ну или когда каждому вошьют идентификационный чип под кожу. :-) Кстати, хорошая идея - идентифицировать не головы на изображении а лежащие у каждого в кармане сотовые телефоны. :-)

Comment: Задача отнюдь не тривиальна. К примеру, допустим вы использовали нейронку для нахождения людей на изображении, вы можете их подсчитать таким образом, но только на одном изображении! Если это видео (поток изображений) и количество людей может меняться + могут быть разные люди (один ушел, второй зашёл), то помимо обнаружения их нужно идентифицировать. Хорошо, если лицо на изображении будет видно, а если нет... Да и сверка с базой уже записанных лиц при большом количестве тоже сложная задача.